# GridViewColumn header alignemenet

Tags: wpf, header, alignment, gridviewcolumn

I have a GridView:

```
<GridViewColumn Width="{Binding ElementName=helperField, Path=ActualWidth}" >
    <GridViewColumn.Header>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Static lang:TextResource.name}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" />
            <TextBlock Margin="20,0,0,0" Text="{Binding SelectedWorkingDate.WorkingDate.Date, StringFormat=d}" Width="100" />
            <TextBlock Margin="0,0,17,0" Text="{x:Static lang:TextResource.workingtime_time}" Width="80"  />
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Static lang:TextResource.desc}" Margin="15,0,0,0" Width="300" HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </StackPanel>
    </GridViewColumn.Header>
```

...

Now my gridViewColumn filling all the available space, but the header also is moving after f.e. maximizing the window.
What can I do to have explicit position of my StackPanel in the header.

I have also created a blank project with ListView, set the GridViewColumn width="900" and see the same behavior, so maybe there is a property I should use to change that behavior?

Comment: What you you mean by _have explicit position of my StackPanel in the header_? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I mean it should not be moved when the column width is resizing

Comment: Do I understand correct that you use `ListView` and you want your header to be left aligned?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Canvas:

```
<Canvas>
   <TextBlock Canvas.Top="20" Canvas.Left="20" Text="{x:Static lang:TextResource.name}"
</Canvas>
```